# Is enabling Hyper-V is requisite to run the emulator for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is it NOT possible to run the emulator for Windows Phone 8 only by installing the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 with Visual Studio 2013 without enabling Hyper-V for the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Yes the Hyper-V is required, the reason I needed to buy a new laptop.  It uses the virtual machine system / setup to run up a VM for the phone.   In fact, you cannot start MS virtual machine manager on a PC without Hyper-v

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

```
 System requirements
     •In the BIOS, the following features must be supported:

          ◦Hardware-assisted virtualization.

 Hyper-V requirements
   •In the BIOS, the following features must be enabled:

     ◦Hardware-assisted virtualization.
     ◦Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
     ◦Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).

 •In Windows, Hyper-V must be enabled and running.

 •You have to be a member of the local Hyper-V Administrators group.
```

Comment: You can develop apps and even deploy to a physical device connected via USB. You cannot however use a emulator.

Comment: Oh ! I get it ! One more clarification, It also says that the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 setup program checks the prerequisites for running Windows Phone 8 Emulator and It displays warnings if the prerequisites are not present, but it does not require them. My laptop does not support AMD hardware-assisted virtualization. Does it mean I can still run emulator for Windows Phone 8 if I install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 ? Or I only have the choice of using a real device?

Comment: @IsharaAmarasekera There is no way to run the emulator in your situation.  I must say that I totally agree with Lukkha about the device.  You will save yourself LOADS of time by just buying a really cheap phone and deploy to it.  On my new i7 it was still factor of 10x slower than using the physical device - don't know why.  On android it was specifically the case.   I am writing cross platform.